# Angular 4 - Remove current dynamic component programmatically

Tags: angular

I have created some dynamic components like -

```
<div>
  <ang-textfield></ang-textfield>
  <ang-textarea></ang-textarea>
  <ang-checkbox></ang-checkbox>
</div>
```

Within specific `dynamic component` there are some elements like -

```
<ang-textfield>
  <input type="text" />
  <button>Settings</button>
  <button (click)="remove_component()">Remove</button>
</ang-textfield>
```

I want to remove current component after clicking `Remove` button.

How can i do that?

**Here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/pW7Zsy6s73lHgJHLO0lC)**

Comment: remove from where?

Comment: How did you create them?

Comment: I have created these dynamic components from drag elements within drop area. Now I need to delete specific dynamic component after clicking delete button within the component.

Comment: Please create minimal reproduction on plunker

Comment: @yurzui i'm doing that, thanks

Comment: I don't see any dynamic components creation in your plunker

Comment: I didn't do that here, I just need to delete current component after clicking remove button

Comment: I used following code to add dynamic component - `let component = factory
            .create(viewContainerRef.parentInjector);
        viewContainerRef.insert(component.hostView);`

Comment: I think you are looking for the following check this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/dynamic)

Comment: just call `viewContainerRef.remove(index)`

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com how can i get the index of my current `Component`?

Comment: `viewContainerRef.indexOf(component.hostView)`

Answer (score 2):

You can Pass the component factory as a Reference to the Dynamic Build Component and then in the Dynamic Component Have a button Destroy .

This [**Gist**](https://gist.github.com/rahulrsingh09/271aaff4cb134685ed7a62197670938c#file-27-ts) will give you a Clearer Idea.

A live [**Example**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/dynamic)