# Angular 4 - get ViewRef of current component

Tags: angular

How can i get the `ViewRef` of my current `component` -

I am trying to get `ViewRef` from a service. Here is the code -

*component.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable, ViewRef } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CheckboxService{

constructor(private viewRef: ViewRef){
}

getViewRef(){
    return this.viewRef;
}
}
```

*component.ts*

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output, ViewChild, ViewRef } from 
'@angular/core';
import { AddFormDirective } from '../../add-form/add-form.directives';
import { CheckboxService } from './checkbox.service';

@Component({
selector: 'ang-checkbox',
templateUrl: './checkbox.component.html'
})

export class CheckboxViewComponent {

@ViewChild(AddFormDirective) addFormDirective: AddFormDirective;

constructor(private checkboxService: CheckboxService){
}

remove_element(){
    let viewContainerRef = this.addFormDirective.viewContainerRef;
    let currentComponentIndex = 
    viewContainerRef.indexOf(this.checkboxService.getViewRef());
    viewContainerRef.remove(currentComponentIndex);
}
}
```

I get following error -

> No provider for ViewRef!

What is the best way to get `ViewRef` of current component?

Comment: The best way is to get it after creation some component dynamically

Comment: What do you want to do with `ViewRef`? Seems you want to remove the component from inside it. I don't think it's a good idea to try to remove a component imperatively that was added by Angular.

Comment: Provide the `ViewRef` in the constructor of the component.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46376328/angular-4-remove-current-dynamic-component-programmatically

Comment: Please provide minimal working example of how you are creating your components

Comment: @yurzui, thanks for your help, problem solved. I did assign child component's `viewRef` when i dynamically created components. So, at real time it gets assigned information and can  remove `ViewRef` from `ViewContainerRef`

Answer (score 5):

Inject the `ChangeDetectorRef`.

```
export class ExampleComponent {
   constructor(@Inject(ChangeDetectorRef) view: ViewRef) {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. resolve Component to componentFactory with ComponentFactoryResolver;
2. get ComponentRef from the method of ViewContainerRef which call createComponent;
3. access ComponentRef['hostView'].