# Get element within ViewContainerRef without knowing its index?

Tags: angular

https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef

If I want to use Angular's `ViewContainerRef` to `move()` a specific child around, do I have more capabilities to select it than just using `get(index)`? I see it has a `indexOf(ViewRef)` method, but I can't figure out how to get a `ViewRef` in Angular without returning it from a `ViewContainerRef` in the first place.

For example, if I create a ViewContainerRef like the following, how could I get a `ViewRef` of the `#button` element so I can move it, without being sure of its current index? Is there any way to use the button `ViewChild` in this scenario?

```
  @ViewChild('list', {read: ViewContainerRef}) list: ViewContainerRef;
  @ViewChild('button') button;
```

```
<div #list>
    ...
    <button #button>Toggle</button>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, I'm not even really sure now if this `@ViewChild(... {read: ViewContainerRef})` even gives me what I want, because `get()` doesn't return anything for any index. So uh, I'll have to fiddle a bit.

Comment: One way to have access to the ViewRef is dynamically building your ViewContainer. As you can see in the documentaion of ViewContainerRef, the insert inside the ViewContainer returns a ViewRef. You can read more about it here: https://blog.rangle.io/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-2/

Comment: Btw, there's this similar question where the the guy wanted to remove a component instead of moving like you need, but it's similar:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46376328/angular-4-remove-current-dynamic-component-programmatically